# Update Android Studio 0.9.9 to 1.x.x possible?

Tags: android-studio, updates, beta

I am having problems updating Android Studio from 0.8.4 to 1.x.x (currently 1.1.0)

The first thing I did was to update on the beta channel to 0.9.9

This worked quite well (after applying a change on Gradle build types from `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled`)

This update mentioned something like `it will enable updating Android Studio to 1.0.0`

After restarting Android Studio, it told me that `Android Studio is ready to update`. But after clicking on `update` I can only Download and not `Update & Restart` the newest version 1.1.0

When I download and install it, it cannot use the old installation folder because it wanted me to select an empty folder.

How can I enable updating from 0.9.9 to 1.x.x? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame my inner resistance and installed the full version 1.1.0 yesterday.

It was a quite easy task, all of my settings were found and also my project was opened correctly. It was also immediately buildable.

But: After that I had two parallel Android installations, so I uninstalled the beta version 0.9.9. I was quite shocked when I saw that the uninstaller joyfully removed parts of the new 1.1.0 installation, too.

The good news is: For some reason it removed the new SDK installation from version 1.1.0 and kept the old SDK of version 0.9.9 (same SDK version!). My project is still running, so everything is fine. It was only pretty confusing ...